# Local of locals with similar names

Tags: local, stata, shortcut

I need to create a local like this:

```
local dummy1 = "var3 var4"
local dummy2 = "var6 var7"
local dummies = "`dummy1' `dummy2'"
```

But I need to use this in different databases where the number of locals `dummy1`, `dummy2`, `dummy3`,...is unknown.
Basically what I need is to do something like this but properly:

```
local dummies = "dummy*"
```

where dummy* are locals instead of variables.

Comment: Please describe your situation "where the number of locals dummy1, dummy2, dummy3,...is unknown." Is there a pattern for the dummy variable names? How do you identify them across datasets?

Comment: No patern for the variable names, the only pattern is with the locals. The locals were created ex-ante by hand

Comment: Is it always the case that if one of the variables included in a dummy local is present, then all the variables in that local are present?

Comment: yes, they dont always have the same number of variables though

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that might help you along your way.

```
. local dummy1 a1 b1 c1

. local dummy2 d2 e2

. local dummy3 f3 g3

. local dummies

. forvalues i = 1/42 {
  2.    local dummies `dummies' `dummy`i''
  3.    }

. display "`dummies'
a1 b1 c1 d2 e2 f3 g3

.
```

Comment: It is a useful step, but what I need is the number 3 in your example to be generated automatically depending on the number of locals called dummy there are.

Comment: What process is creating the `dummy*` locals? Could it not at the same time create the local `ndummy`?

Comment: I changed the `forvalues` loop to run from 1 to 42 instead of 1 to 3; substitute for 42 whatever number exceeds the maximum number of dummies you are likely to have.